# compare string value with the parameter passing using MDX Query

Tags: mdx, mondrian

Actually i m not able to compare string value with the parameter inside the iff condition.
can any one tell me where i m wrong .for your ref here i m mentioning my code

```
IIF(${parFranchise}='TIPPER',
    {[Product.Franchise Hierarchy].[SKU Category].[${parLOB}].CHILDREN},
```

Comment: can any one help me on that ..how i can achieved this ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try

```
IIF( '${parFranchise}' ='TIPPER',
     {[Product.Franchise Hierarchy].[SKU Category].[${parLOB}].CHILDREN},
```